# Dell R210 Supports 3d Graphics

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have got Dell R210 ii e3-1230v2 dedicated server. I have installed Ubuntu 12 but it does not recognize the onboard graphic card. When I install vmware workstation 12 on it and install a guest OS, the guest claims that it has no 3D support.

Is there a way to run simple 3D graphic things in this server?

Comment: Please, explain better what's your situation and what are the kind of *things* you want to run. What doesn't recognize the graphics card, Ubuntu or just VMware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dell R210 comes with a Matrox G200eW GPU with 8MB of video memory.  This is an *ancient* GPU with almost no memory.  While it is *technically* a 3D capable GPU, it is really only used for modern day 2D needs.  I would suspect software 3D rendering might be faster than this card.

The R200 series is the lowest end rack mounted server Dell makes and you get what you pay for.